# Trying to work with 2 Displays on Windows 10

Tags: windows, laptop, multiple-monitors, hdmi, taskbar

I am trying to work with 2 monitors on my Win10 Laptop. One being the main laptop screen ofc and the other a LED TV I recently bought.

Now when I connect them via HDMI and select "Extend these displays" for the most part they work fine. But -

How do I switch games on displays? No matter what I do and from which display I open my games they always run on my laptop display. How do I switch them between my TV and laptop display. (I've tried Windows key + arrow keys).

Comment: Welcome to [su]! Please try and ask 1 question at a time (otherwise your question will be closed as too broad). 
Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and [On-Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @DavidPostill Never Mind I resolved one of em...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this isn't much of a solution, I'll label it a workaround.

There are a lot of solutions [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/138531/how-to-move-a-fullscreen-game-to-the-second-monitor).

However I personally did this-
Start your game, it will start up on the main monitor (my laptop monitor in this case), then press windows key + p and select external monitor only. Once your game is open again press windows key + p and select duplicate displays. Your game stay on the second display while you'll get the second display to work.

What this does is - this method sets the external monitor as the primary display only when the game is launching, and then reverts the change, hence you trick your computer into believing that the external monitor is the primary display and it has to start the game there. *Humans are smart eh?*

Alternatively you could just set the external display as your primary monitor, our could use some of the answers on the page I linked.

Comment: Could you post a solution you used here? Just linking to another post makes this a very poor answer.

Comment: Sure @SimonSheehan , post edited